# Accessing objects(basic)

Tags: javascript, object

I have a(most likely simple and bumd) question about objects. I created the object "jon" of the instance "Person". When I call

```
console.log(jon.name)
```

the console will give me out "jon". So far so good.

After running the code and typing in the console itself

```
jon.name
```

I was expecting to get "jon" as a result, but the console showed me that jon is undefined. Could someone explain me why?

Here´s a code snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/Fasyx/w0q1rqh0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in jsfiddle runs in scope of another function or some kind of a send-box that's why variable `jon` is not available in global scope.

If you create simple html file with `<script>` tag with you code inside and open it in browser you will get the behavior you expect:

```
<script>
    var Person = function(name, age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    var jon = new Person("jon", 24);
    console.log(jon.name + " " + jon.age)
</script>
```

If you access `jon` in console you will find the object because it is part of global scope now.

Comment: Ah, just set up a server and run .html with the script in there. Perfect - thank you Andrii!